# i18n Localization in React with Material UI by extending Typography?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization, material-ui, i18next

I was beginning the painful job of adding the `useTranslation` hook of `react-i18next` to all my components when I thought that I could use the `Typography` component of MaterialUI (already in my app) to hide the logic.

➡️ Is there any recommendation/advice to do or not to do so?

➡️ Is that a good idea?

Example

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next'
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core'

const TranslatedTypography = ({children}) => {
    const {t} = useTranslation()

    return <Typography>{t(children)}</Typography>
}
```

Comment: That seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not fit every use case (for example for a button text where the hook is used) but here is what I've used:

```js
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next'
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import React from 'react'

const TranslatedTypography = ({
    children,
    i18nKey,
    count = 1,
    ...otherProps
}) => {
    return (
        <Typography {...otherProps}>
            <Trans i18nKey={i18nKey} count={count}>
                {children}
            </Trans>
        </Typography>
    )
}

export default TranslatedTypography
```

And you can use it as follow:

```
<TranslatedTypography
    i18nKey="yourKey"
    variant="h6">
  title
</TranslatedTypography>
```

Note: it seems you can also omit the `i18nKey` prop and put the key directly as the children.